# Inheriting a method in the style of 'before_filter'

Tags: ruby

i want to write a method that is available in a child class in the same way that `before filter` is in Ruby on Rails, and can be used in a similar way.

Here is the code that I expected to work:

```
# presenter_test.rb

module Presenter
  def presenting(model_name)
    # do generic stuff
  end
end

class ApplicationPresenter
  include Presenter
end

class ArticlePresenter < ApplicationPresenter
  presenting :article
end
```

But when running it with `ruby presenter_test.rb` I get the following error:

```
presenting_test.rb:12:in `<class:ArticlePresenter>': 
  undefined method `presenting' for ArticlePresenter:Class (NoMethodError)
from presenting_test.rb:11:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Hint: what is the class of `ArticlePresenter`? Hint #2: it is not `ApplicationPresenter`.

Comment: use extend instead of include

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `ActiveSupport::Concern` and do something like this:

```
module Presenter
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  module ClassMethods
    def presenting(model_name)
      # do generic stuff
    end
  end
end
```

Then your classes should work as expected.

Comment: Thanks, using ClassMethods got me to the solution!

Answer (score 1):

Using poros as your example:

```
module Presenter
  def presenting(model_name)
    puts model_name.to_s
  end
end

class ApplicationPresenter
  extend Presenter
end

class ArticlePresenter < ApplicationPresenter
  presenting :article
end
article
=> nil

ArticlePresenter.new.presenting('hi')
hi
=> nil
```